# Flexbox layout breaking on Safari Browser

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a chat message style page using bootstrap and custom CSS code. The code is working fine on chrome browser but on Safari mobile and desktop the layout is breaking.

The problem is that the message divs with images are overlapping means images and text are showing on top of each other. If you run the sample code below the last two messages are showing on top of each other. On the Chrome browser, it is showing correctly.

I even checked and prefixed all my CSS so it works on a different browser but it doesn't seem to be affecting the Safari browser.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```css
.messages div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.messages {
  height: 69vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.profile-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.message {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .messages {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .profile-image {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }
  .avatar-circle-sm {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }
  .avatar-circle-sm .initials {
    top: 2.5px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.attachments {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.attachments a {
  color: #0056b3;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.attachments .upload-preview {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.profile-image {
  -o-object-fit: cover !important;
  object-fit: cover !important;
}

.dropdown.settings .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.settings .dropdown-toggle {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}

.msg:hover {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.msg:hover .dropdown.settings .dropdown-toggle {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown.settings .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown.settings .dropdown-menu li i {
  width: 20px;
}

.dropdown.settings .dropdown-menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.files-container {
  max-height: 235px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.msg {
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.date-row {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
}

.date-row-fixed {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .msg {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
  }
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.attachments:before,
.attachments:after,
.d-flex:before,
.d-flex:after {
  content: normal;
}

.attachments div {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card" style="max-width: 1000px;">
        <div class="card-header">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Messages - Safari Test </div>
        <div class="card-body p-0">
          <div class="messages" style="height: 732px;">
            <div class="date-row">Thursday, April 2, 2020</div>
            <div class="sender msg d-flex" data-id="1" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">User 2</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="delete-msg"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span class="ml-1">Delete</span></li>
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-02 11:21:53">4:51 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message mt-2">Hello </div>
                <div class="attachments">
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="receiver msg d-flex" data-id="5" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">User 1</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-02 11:33:58">5:03 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message mt-2">Hello </div>
                <div class="attachments">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sender msg d-flex" data-id="7" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">User 2</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="delete-msg"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span class="ml-1">Delete</span></li>
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-02 14:59:20">8:29 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message mt-2">hi. This is a test message Testing 123 </div>
                <div class="attachments">
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sender msg d-flex" data-id="8" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
              <div class="avatar" style="display: none;">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <div class="message mt-2" style="margin-left: 50px; flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">Testing another message 123 </div>
                  <span class="font-weight-bold" style="display: none;">User 2</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-direction: row;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="delete-msg"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span class="ml-1">Delete</span></li>
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-02 14:59:29" style="visibility: hidden;">8:29 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="attachments" style="margin-left: 50px;">
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="date-row">Friday, April 3, 2020</div>
            <div class="receiver msg d-flex" data-id="24" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">User 1</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-03 03:47:05" style="visibility: visible;">9:17 AM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message mt-2">JE </div>
                <div class="attachments">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sender msg d-flex" data-id="26" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
              <div class="avatar">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">User 2</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="delete-msg"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span class="ml-1">Delete</span></li>
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-03 16:56:20" style="visibility: visible;">10:26 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message mt-2">this is some text </div>
                <div class="attachments">
                  <a href="https://place-hold.it/200x200" download="dog1.jpg"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> dog1.jpg <small class="text-muted ml-1">133.63 KB</small>
                                            <span class="delete-attachment ml-2" style="font-size: 16px;" data-attachment="5e876ab40dc05.jpg" data-id="5"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200" class="upload-preview mb-2" alt="Upload Preview">
                                            </div>
                                        </a>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sender msg d-flex" data-id="27" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
              <div class="avatar" style="display: none;">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://place-hold.it/50x50" class="profile-image" alt="User Profile">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="body ml-2 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0">
                  <div class="message mt-2" style="margin-left: 50px; flex-grow: unset; flex-direction: unset; justify-content: unset;">some text and 2 images </div>
                  <span class="font-weight-bold" style="display: none;">User 2</span>
                  <div class="d-flex" style="flex-direction: row;">
                    <div class="dropdown settings">
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle text-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li class="delete-msg"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <span class="ml-1">Delete</span></li>
                        <li class="quote-msg"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> <span class="ml-1">Quote</span></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-secondary msg-time ml-2" data-time="2020-04-03 16:56:57" style="visibility: hidden;">10:26 PM</span>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="attachments" style="margin-left: 50px;">
                  <a href="https://place-hold.it/200x200" download="dog3.jpg"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> dog3.jpg <small class="text-muted ml-1">176.37 KB</small>
                                            <span class="delete-attachment ml-2" style="font-size: 16px;" data-attachment="5e876ad937e50.jpg" data-id="6"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200" class="upload-preview mb-2" alt="Upload Preview">
                                            </div>
                                        </a>

                  <a href="https://place-hold.it/200x200" download="dog2.jpg"><i class="fas fa-file"></i> dog2.jpg <small class="text-muted ml-1">81.61 KB</small>
                                            <span class="delete-attachment ml-2" style="font-size: 16px;" data-attachment="5e876ad9386be.jpg" data-id="7"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                                            <div>
                                                <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200" class="upload-preview mb-2" alt="Upload Preview">
                                            </div>
                                        </a>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need more divs.